# Error in my VBA Code. Function Show in Inner Dictionary Increases Count by 1

Tags: class, excel, dictionary, vba

I created 2 Classes. An Internal_Dict with items of type "double" and an external Dict with items of type Internal_Dict. Both classes have a Show procedure to print the data. I created a test procedure to verifies both classes. Internal_Dict it's Ok but External_Dict has an issue: when the trace enter the show function the count increases by one. It creates a new item with an empty key. That generates an error when try to print that new item.

```
Class Module IntDict  
'private Attributes  
Private pInternalDict As Scripting.Dictionary

'Class Initialize/Terminate methods  
Private Sub Class_Initialize()  
Set pInternalDict = New Scripting.Dictionary  
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()  
Set pInternalDict = Nothing  
End Sub

'Add/Count/Items/Item/Remove/Remove All Methods  
Public Function Add(Key As Variant, Item As Double)  
pInternalDict.Add Key:=Key, Item:=Item  
End Function

Public Function Update(Key As Variant, Item As Double)  
If pInternalDict.Exists(Key) Then  
    pInternalDict.Item(Key) = pInternalDict.Item(Key) + Item  
Else  
    pInternalDict.Add Key:=Key, Item:=Item  
End If  
End Function

Public Property Get Count() As Long  
Count = pInternalDict.Count  
End Property

Public Property Get Items() As Scripting.Dictionary  
Set Items = pInternalDict  
End Property

Public Property Get Item(vItem As Variant) As Double  
Item = pInternalDict.Item(vItem)  
End Property

Public Function Exists(vItem As Variant) As Boolean  
Exists = pRentas.Exists(vItem)  
End Function

Public Sub Show()  
Dim vKey As Variant

For Each vKey In pInternalDict.Keys  
    Debug.Print vKey & "|" & pInternalDict.Item(vKey)  
Next  
End Sub

Class Module ExtDict  
'private Attributes  
Private pExternalDict As Scripting.Dictionary  

'Class Initialize/Terminate methods  
Private Sub Class_Initialize()   
Set pExternalDict = New Scripting.Dictionary  
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()  
Set pExternalDict = Nothing  
End Sub

'Add/Count/Items/Item/Remove/Remove All Methods  
Public Function Add(Key As Variant, Item As CInternalDict)  
pExternalDict.Add Key:=Key, Item:=Item  
End Function

Public Function Update(ExternalKey As Variant, InternalKey As Variant,   Item As Double)  
Dim newIntDict As CInternalDict  

If pExternalDict.Exists(ExternalKey) Then  
    With pExternalDict.Item(ExternalKey)  
        Call .Update(InternalKey, Item)  
    End With  
Else  
    Set newIntDict = New CInternalDict  
    newIntDict.Add Key:=InternalKey, Item:=Item  
    pExternalDict.Add Key:=ExternalKey, Item:=newIntDict  
End If  
End Function

Public Property Get Count() As Long  
Count = pExternalDict.Count  
End Property

Public Property Get Items() As Scripting.Dictionary  
Set Items = pExternalDict  
End Property

Public Property Get Item(vItem As Variant) As CRentasCasa  
Item = pExternalDict.Item(vItem)  
End Property

Public Function Exists(vItem As Variant) As Boolean  
Exists = pExternalDict.Exists(vItem)  
End Function

Public Sub Show()  
Dim vKey As Variant  
Dim dItem As CInternalDict  

For Each vKey In pExternalDict.Keys  
    Debug.Print vKey 'Print external key  
    Set dItem = pExternalDict.Item(vKey)  
    dItem.Show 'Show Internal Dict  
Next  
End Sub

=========================
'Externals procedures

Sub Test_InternalDict() 'It's OK  
Dim myIntDict As CInternalDict  

Set myIntDict = New CInternalDict  
    myIntDict.Update "IntBox1", 1500  
    myIntDict.Update "IntBox2", 1800  
    myIntDict.Update "IntBox1", 200  
    myIntDict.Update "IntBox2", 100  
    myIntDict.Update "IntBox1", 100  
    myIntDict.Update "IntBox3", 1500  
    myIntDict.Update "IntBox4", 1900  
    myIntDict.Show  
Set myIntDict = Nothing  
End Sub

'Creates the ExternalDict in the right way but show call has a bad behavior  
Sub Test_ExternalDict()   
Dim myExtDict As CExternalDict

Set myExtDict = New CExternalDict  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox1", 6, 1500  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox1", 8, 1800  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox2", 5, 100  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox3", 7, 1900  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox1", 7, 1600  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox2", 8, 1900  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox3", 4, 100  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox1", 7, 300  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox2", 5, 1400  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox3", 4, 1500  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox1", 6, 200  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox3", 5, 200  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox3", 5, 1800  
    myExtDict.Update "ExtBox3", 7, -100  
    myExtDict.Show 'ERROR. Add an Item when enter in the Show Function  
Set myExtDict = Nothing
End Sub`
```

'Any clue????

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The code i right!!!

Vba dictionary has an issue when accessing and item that not exists: vba creates an empty item with an empty key.

The code never evaluate a not existing element but in the watch window I have an expression that was viewing an external variable of dictionary type. When entering to the module show, the watching expression add an item.

I just cleaned the watching window.